# Best way to hold and then display employee information on a page?

Tags: html, mysql, django

I hope everyone's doing well.
I am making a little Time Attendance Application where the employee Checks in and Checks out. I am making this a Web App based on the Django python framework. 
I want to understand the best way to hold the data of these employees but then also display it in a separate page for each employee.

So far, I've made a table in my `MySQL` like:

```
INSERT INTO employees (employee_id INT(50), first_name VARCHAR(25), last_name VARCHAR(30), age INT(80), mobile_no VARCHAR(16), email VARCHAR(100)`
```

Everytime I want to create a new employee, I have a page that opens and takes in the employee's details and inserts everything to the database.

I also have a table on the homepage (that only the admin can see) that displays the employees and their details but if we click a `tr`, I want it to open a page containing that employee's details so I can change anything I want or even delete that employee.

I understand that the page will have to fetch the details about that employee from the database and then anything I change and save the changes of, will be modified in the database.
It's just like how you would change your account details from a webpage.
But, how do I go on about displaying this whole page?

Do I make the page by scratch? Is there something that Django provides for doing this? I am very new to Django.

Thank You for you time ^.^

Comment: Django has a built-in admin site functionality, but if that page is intended to be used by your average manager (non-technical), you should create a page yourself and set the appropriate permissions so only him can access it.

Comment: That aside, you just need to create another view, set up a route for it, and make a <a href> link to that view in your <table>. Where are you stuck?

Comment: What on Earth is INT(80)?

Comment: Holy cow Strawberry have some mercy on my soul. I'm new to SQL xD

Comment: And thank you Hugo. I've elaborated question a bit more down on Mudassar's answer. Also, how do permissions work in Django? Could I maybe get a link or something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create two types of views in your application views.py.
1. List view to list out all the entries in table. 
2. Detail view to see the detail related to single table.

So your both views will be mentioned in your urls.py. Now what you can do is that you can set a "href" tag on the table value that will link it to detail page with `<a href="{ url 'detail' employee.id %}>{{ employee_name}}</a>`.

In this case whenever you will click on employee name it will take you to the detail page for that particular employee. I am assuming that you've created your views/urls with reference of employee_id. Or you can go ahead and see the details about setting up "get_absolute_url" in official docs. As much information without code you've provided this much I can tell you. Good Luck :-)

Comment: Thank you. I understand that I need to do that, but what I don't understand is how I'd make the "details" page that you're talking. I now realize that I should've elaborated my question more clearly. So, do I add PHP to my page and connect it to the database so it loads the right details in the appropriate places, or is it something to do with Django.

Comment: You need to choose one of the platform PHP or Django. If you chose Django then you don't need PHP at all. I can't create a whole application for you here but I can suggest you best way to do it. Follow official link or you can even go to Youtube.com and there a lot of tutorials help you create similar like this. Follow the tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/ its official and after completing this you will get the idea to lay down structure of any basic application the way you are trying to do.